# Cannot read docs, inserted into mongodb using pymongo, with mongo shell

Tags: python, mongodb, python-3.x, pymongo

I am running the following code in python 3.4

```
import pymongo
conn = pymongo.MongoClient()
db1 = conn["db1"]
movie = {"name": "Avengers", "year": 2012}
db1.movies.insert(movie)
conn.close()
```

When i am trying to read the doc in mongo shell using the following commands, it just returns nothing.

```
use db1
db.db1.movies.find()
```

Comment: `db.movies.find()`

Comment: Please edit the title to better explain what you are asking.

Comment: Thank you. It helped. Please suggest a title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no need to call `db.db1` just use `db`

```
use db1
db.movies.find()
```

Comment: Thank you. The tutorial I watched always used "db.db1", so I used the same. I didn't know it was this simple of a mistake. Anyways, thanks again.